# dokku error: cannot find entity for app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

trying to restart dokku after a server reboot. Everything I do (redis:link, dokku deploy, pushing a new version of the app from my computer..) fails with a could not find entity error message.

```
2014/07/16 09:02:45 Error: Could not find entity for domain_freek
```

I feel like it might have something to do with the docker containers or images, so I tried restarting the latest docker container for the app, but no dice. Dokku still gives me a could not find entity error.

```
root@domainfreek3:/home/dokku/domain_freek# docker restart `cat /home/dokku/domain_freek/CONTAINER`
b5823fa2703f
root@domainfreek3:/home/dokku/domain_freek# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
b5823fa2703f        dokku/domain_freek:latest        /bin/bash -c '/start   6 minutes ago       Up 10 seconds       5000/tcp                  compassionate_tesla   
f6d165a32e92        2c035b41f308                     /bin/bash -c '/start   27 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       5000/tcp                  boring_heisenberg     
96c33f5458de        jezdez/redis:latest              /usr/bin/redis-serve   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       6379/tcp                  redis_domain_freek    
f76d9f0d944b        postgresql/domain_freek:latest   /usr/bin/start_pgsql   24 hours ago        Up 18 hours         0.0.0.0:49153->5432/tcp   sick_einstein         
root@domainfreek3:/home/dokku/domain_freek# dokku deploy domain_freek
-----> Checking status of PostgreSQL
       Found image postgresql/domain_freek database
       Checking status... ok.
2014/07/16 09:04:47 Error: Could not find entity for domain_freek
root@domainfreek3:/home/dokku/domain_freek# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
f6d165a32e92        2c035b41f308                     /bin/bash -c '/start   27 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       5000/tcp                  boring_heisenberg    
96c33f5458de        jezdez/redis:latest              /usr/bin/redis-serve   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       6379/tcp                  redis_domain_freek   
f76d9f0d944b        postgresql/domain_freek:latest   /usr/bin/start_pgsql   24 hours ago        Up 18 hours         0.0.0.0:49153->5432/tcp   sick_einstein
```

Any advice would be appreciated!